# How to set a select value when the page loads in react

Tags: reactjs

I wanted to make a method when the page loads, the value will be set by the first option on the dropdown while using a blank state. However, what I did was onChange events where it only changes value passing states to another function. Is there an event where the page loads, it sets to that selected value?

**Parent.js**

```
const Parent = () => {
  const [choice, setChoice] = useState(""); // <-- Leaving a blank state

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{choice === "" ? "NO VALUE" : choice}</h1> // <-- Displays the default value of 'NO VALUE' when the page loads, otherwise when selecting an option, a value displays
      <Child name={(choice) => setChoice(choice)} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Parent;
```

**Child.js**

```
const Child = ({ name }) => {
  const [filterChoice, setFilterChoice] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Child: " + filterChoice); // <-- Only displays as 'Child: ' and no value whenever it loads the page, otherwise it displays the value selected
  }, [filterChoice]); 

  const setValue = (e) => {
    setFilterChoice(e.target.value);
    name(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <select onChange={(e) => setValue(e)} defaultValue="A">
        <option value="A">A</option>
        <option value="B">B</option>
        <option value="C">C</option>
        <option value="D">D</option>
        <option value="E">E</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Child;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const Child = ({ name }) => {
  const defaultValue = "A";
  const [filterChoice, setFilterChoice] = useState(defaultValue);

  useEffect(() => {
    name(defaultValue);
    console.log("Child: " + filterChoice); // <-- Only displays as 'Child: ' and no value whenever it loads the page, otherwise it displays the value selected
  }, []);
  const setValue = (e) => {
    setFilterChoice(e.target.value);
    name(e.target.value);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <select onChange={(e) => setValue(e)} defaultValue={defaultValue}>
        <option value="A">A</option>
        <option value="B">B</option>
        <option value="C">C</option>
        <option value="D">D</option>
        <option value="E">E</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  );
};

const Parent = () => {
  const [choice, setChoice] = useState(""); // <-- Leaving a blank state
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{choice === "" ? "NO VALUE" : choice}</h1>
      <Child name={(choice) => setChoice(choice)} />
    </div>
  );
};
export default Parent;
```

Can you try the above solution, I have just set the default value of options in useEffect.

Comment: In the console, it displays the selected value. However, the state re-renders again and set back to the default value which is 'A' in your example. So the display output it still sets to 'A' even when selective different options

Comment: Ah ok.. let me correct it and send the right snippet

Comment: @IrvingReal -  have updated the code, please have a look. Sorry was distracted before with some meeting

I have set in useEffect on initial load to point to default value only for first render just like componentDidMount.

Comment: It did solve my problem. So the main issue was the dependency on the useEffect which constantly changes to the defaultValue of that set value

Comment: Yup...thats right.

Comment: Thanks! It took me a long time to track down this answer, and it worked for me. One note: I find using the key function name as "name" a bit confusing - I changed it to "setter" in implementation, which my be more intuitive to read later.